# In rest controller how we pass value url in key and value form

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc

This my code of rest controller

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/?username={username}&password={password}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
 @ResponseStatus(value= HttpStatus.OK)
 public UserDetails getUserDetails(@PathVariable("username") String username , @PathVariable("password") String password )
 {

     System.out.println("This is controller"+username+","+password);
     UserDetails userDetails = userService.loadUserByUsername(username);
     System.out.println("Get Password "+userDetails.getPassword());
     if(userDetails.getUsername().equals(username) && userDetails.getPassword().equals(password))
     {
         return userDetails;
     }
     return null;
 }
```

When i pass url in postman the out pout will be

http://localhost:8080/hello/?username=abc@gmail.com&password=123456

out put must be return json value but it will print nothing

Comment: @rk13 Please paste your code, not a screenshot. This makes it easier to help you.

Answer (score 0):

First thing first, follow standards as its helpful. 
Now coming to your answer, you can use `@RequestParam` in this case. An example (as I can't copy paste your code. See! this happens).

```
@RequestMapping("urlstring")
  public String printUserDept (@RequestParam("dept") String deptName) {
  //your code
  return "viewname";
}
```

and your url will be `example.com/urlstring?dept=departmentname`

Comment: In URL i.e `urlstring?dept=something`

Answer (score 0):

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
 @ResponseStatus(value= HttpStatus.OK)
 public UserDetails getUserDetails(@RequestParam("username") String username , @RequestParam("password") String password )
 {

     System.out.println("This is controller"+username+","+password);
     UserDetails userDetails = userService.loadUserByUsername(username);
     System.out.println("Get Password "+userDetails.getPassword());
     if(userDetails.getUsername().equals(username) && userDetails.getPassword().equals(password))
     {
         return userDetails;
     }
     return null;
 }
```